# Java Executor - Single Thread Multiple Task

Tags: java, executor

Can an Executor run multiple tasks on a single thread?

Obviously the task execution cannot happen simultaneously with only one physical core to run on, but is there a way to wait or yield so the other submitted tasks can run?

If there is not a wait then how else can one determine, generally, when the other task will run?

Comment: The other task will run when the one that ran before it completes, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes that seems to be the case.  Have to wait until complete in FIFO order.

Comment: Well, that's something you should research. Unless there is an underlying queue that is processed, it's entirely possible that Task 2 might get executed before Task 1 I think. In that case, you know Task 1 will run as soon as Task 2 completes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Not with the current implementations.

No.

;)

Consider the documentation on SingleThreadExecutor (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor()), and [Wait between tasks with SingleThreadExecutor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987395/wait-between-tasks-with-singlethreadexecutor) on StackOverflow.

You could implement your own thread-sharing lock between threads, and run them on a multi-thread executor... but if you want someone else's implementation to do that, well, as far as I know, you're out of luck.